# Unable to add user properties in LDAP Server using Apache Directory Studio on my eclipse using LDAP browser

Tags: eclipse, ldap

I have configured LDAP Server From Apache Directory Studio on my eclipse. I have created user and set the password as well.

Now I have to add the user properties and their values from eclipse- LDAP Browser like  userName,userFaxNumber,userPhoneNo,userDesignation....

Please find the attached step:
[image]

[image]

[image]
while trying to add it I am getting below error:

> Error while executing LDIF - [LDAP: error code 16 - NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE:
>   failed for MessageType : MODIFY_REQUES java.lang.Exception: 
>   [LDAP:
>   error code 16 - NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE: failed for
>   MessageType : MODIFY_REQUEST Message ID : 20 Modify Request Object :
>   'uid=user1,ou=system' Modification[0] Operation : add Modification
>   userFaxNumber:
>   222222org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ModifyRequestImpl@a224a2db:
>   ERR_04269 ATTRIBUTE_TYPE for OID userfaxnumber does not exist!] at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1374)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$9(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1342)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$4.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:736)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1269)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1205)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.modifyEntry(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:758)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.importLdifRecord(ImportLdifRunnable.java:515)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ImportLdifRunnable.importLdif(ImportLdifRunnable.java:272)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ExecuteLdifRunnable.executeLdif(ExecuteLdifRunnable.java:157)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.ExecuteLdifRunnable.run(ExecuteLdifRunnable.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.UpdateEntryRunnable.run(UpdateEntryRunnable.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:116)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>   [LDAP: error code 16 - NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE: failed for MessageType :
>   MODIFY_REQUEST Message ID : 20 Modify Request Object :
>   'uid=gridcomm22,ou=system' Modification[0] Operation : add
>   Modification rlSubmitterFaxNumber:
>   222222org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ModifyRequestImpl@a224a2db:
>   ERR_04269 ATTRIBUTE_TYPE for OID userfaxnumber does not exist!]

Please help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Appears that "userfaxnumber" does NOT exist within the objectclasses for this user. Which LDAP Implementation is being used?